# With admin account how to get the serial no of remote machine in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, wmi

I am getting exception as **Invalid Username**. Since admin account is added to each machine so i want to get the SerialNo of the hostmachine.

```
ConnectionOptions oConn = new ConnectionOptions();
            oConn.Username = "ADMIN";
            oConn.Password = "*******";

            try
            {
            System.Management.ManagementScope oMs = new System.Management.ManagementScope("ABCD", oConn);
            System.Management.ObjectQuery oQuery = new System.Management.ObjectQuery("select SerialNumber from Win32_BaseBoard");
            ManagementObjectSearcher oSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(oMs,oQuery);

            ManagementObjectCollection oReturnCollection = oSearcher.Get();

            foreach( ManagementObject oReturn in oReturnCollection )
            {
            Console.WriteLine("Serial Number : " + oReturn["SerialNumber"].ToString());
            }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is catch Block"+ex.Message);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Have you just told the entire universe your admin password???

Comment: Thanks @TonyHopkinson i didnt notice because i really dont know how to hot remote machine from my local machine?